# LFSR (Linear Feedback Shift Register)

Tags: finite-fields

Given polynomial $P(x)=x^6+x^3+1$ belonging to $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$. Build an $LFSR$ corresponding to $P(x)$. Then find the maximal period of its output sequence and the initial state that could lead to the maximal period output sequence.

Could someone help me?

maximal period=2^n-1
63 if its primitive polynomial
initial state=?

Comment: You are (presumably) receiving downvotes (and no attention to your question) because you do not show any effort of your own. Please show what you have done so far and try to explain precisely where you are having difficulty.

Comment: Also, please make sure that I have not mistakenly changed the meaning of your question.

Comment: WHY IS THE TITLE SHOUTING?!

Comment: @kahen I fixed it.

Comment: Search for more questions on LFSRs on this site for examples. Dilip Sarwate has given some IMHO very illuminative answers here.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $x^9+1=(x^3+1)(x^6+x^3+1)$ so your feedback polynomial is not primitive.